# Flask_Sqlalchemy not importing correctly? Python

Tags: python, sql, postgresql, flask-sqlalchemy

Hello I am working through a Udemy class, and having trouble with an import:

```
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
```

This is what I am using to import sqlalchemy, and its giving me an error about an unresolved attribute error "Column" from SQL Alchemy from the line:

```
id=db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
```

Driving me crazy, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What is `db` here?

Comment: Please post all your code. Do you instantiate db as an SQLAlchemy() object?

Comment: Do check if your orm class is inheriting `db.Model` correctly